# Strange parallel lines in the middle of the basin

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem

[image]

I prepared a stream network for my study area using ArcGIS. Why am I seeing those strange lines in the middle of the map. I used 3 Second SRTM Derived Digital Elevation Model (DEM) from https://ecat.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/69888. Is it because of the DEM I used? In the middle it has desert and there should be lake towards the south.

Comment: Integer DEMs can usually drive the contour algorithm batty, especially with a large flat area. You should always use a low-pass filter to convert to float first.

Comment: What does the DEM look like in that area?

Comment: Would a low-pass filter help? Integer DEM's cannot be magically (or algorithmically) given higher precision that is also accurate, and this is expected and predictable behavior of mathematical function "trying" to map the best pathway across a zone with zero slope.

Comment: Is that section of the DEM a lake?

Comment: This area is a flat area with no discernible flow directions.  This area could be a floodplain, a lake, or an area that you filled.  The flow accumulation tools will just carry on the same vector it enters these area until an outflow point is reached.  I think this paper discussed this problem:  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0098300402000225